# Why is $e^{i2\pi Nf_snT}=1$?

Tags: sampling

Why is $e^{i2\pi Nf_snT}=1$ in snippet from book?

> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because $Tf{_s}$=1 and $N$ and $n$ are integers.  So the exponent becomes 2$\pi$ times an integer, say $K$. But $e{^{i\theta}} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$. Therefore $e{^{i2K\pi}} = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

A try without maths: $x(t)$ gives you your location in the complex plane at time $t$.

The answer is: because when you walk in circles ($2\pi$) an integer number of times, whatever your rotational speed,  or the length of your steps, you finally up end at  the same place as in the beginning, like in   the latin palindromic sentence:

> In girum imus nocte ecce et consumimur igni

which means: "At night we wander in circles and are consumed by fire."

Comment: It's the first time I see the `ecce` in that palindrome.

Comment: From what I still understand from latin, its merely add 4 letters :)